# using configobj to read a complete section one by one

Tags: python, configuration-files, configobj

I am using configobj to read a config file as below.

```
[default]
    PROP1 = "12345"
    PROP2 = "abcde"
[section1]
    PROP1 = "56789"
    PROP2 = ""
[section2]
    PROP1 = ""
    PROP2 = ""
```

I aim to read the list of sections first and then get each section onto a dictionary.  I have to replace with default values if no value is present. say section2 - PROP1 will become "12345".  I have been looking at configobj to read just a section onto a dictionary object, but it looks like there is no function/method to do it.  Any help?

Thanks

Umapathy

Comment: From the accepted answer I understand that you don't need to read sections in order (one by one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read your config file, configobj will convert it into a dictionary for you.

```
>>> from configobj import ConfigObj

>>> config = ConfigObj('your_config_filename')

>>> config.keys()
<<< ['default', 'section1', 'section2']

>>> config['default']
<<< {'PROP1': '12345', 'PROP2': 'abcde'}
```